# Amazon SQS - Make message invisible for x seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an Amazon SQS Queue and I am trying to make it work this way:

- When a new message added to the queue, only the first client who received that message will start work
- For others, the message will be invisible for period of time

Is it possible to do this using Visibility Timeout?

Comment: That is exactly the default behaviour of Amazon SQS.

Answer (score 3):

When a consumer receives and processes a message from SQS queue, the message still remains in the queue (until it is deleted by the consumer). To make sure that other consumers don't process the same message, you can set ***visibility timeout*** of the queue. Once the message has been processed by the consumer, you can delete the message from the queue. For the duration of the visibility timeout, no other consumer will be able to receive and process the same message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to "lock" the message except setting a long `Visibility Timeout`, with a maximum 12 hour timeout.

However, if your real concern also including error/crashing, you can make use of the Dead-Letter-Queue redrive policy, to deal with queue contents that fail to be process indefinitely.